# Dynamically populating dropdown list if records exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have a dropdown list of locations in the UK (towns and Countys) which when selected filter the div elements below via jQuery.

Each user that has set a location has the `id` that relates to that location stored in the `profiles` table.

I want the list to be compiled from a table called `frmlocations` which contains the 1700+ towns. But given the volume of results and that I envisage more mobile traffic than desktop I'd like to filter out the towns that do not have a user 'assigned' to them (or at that location).

I have created a PHP function and experimented with a join but still cannot figure out how to do the filtering.

PHP Code for function:

```
 function get_alllocations() {
        require 'includes/db.config.php';

    $query = "SELECT 
                frmlocations.*
            FROM frmlocations
            JOIN parlours_profiles ON frmlocations.location_city = parlours_profiles.parlour_city
        "; 
    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $all_locations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    return $all_locations;
}
```

Dropdown List Code:

```
<select id="county-select" class="soflow">
    <option value="">Select your location...</option>
      <?php foreach(get_alllocations() as $locationlist): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($locationlist['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($locationlist['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: The JOIN would appear to do the filtering for you, so I'm a little confused. What is your question?

Comment: Yes... How can I adapt the function/query to filter the data that appears in the dropdown list so that it only shows if there is a match to a profile (ie has one result or more) - the join doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Forget about the PHP for a minute, and instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And how should we help you if we do not know how to determine if a city has users associated with it or not?